# Periodic function $f$ with Fourier coefficients $c_n (f)= 1$ for $n\geq 0$ and $-1$ otherwise

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, distribution-theory

What is the periodic generalized function $f \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{T})$ such that (convergence in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{T})$)
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} c_n(f) \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} n x}
\end{equation}
with $c_n(f) = 1$ for $n\geq 0$ and $c_n(f) = -1$ otherwise?

This is somehow the periodic counterpart of the Fourier transform of the Heaviside function (up to an additive constant) but I could not find a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are dealing with $$ 1 + 2i\sum_{n\geq 1}\sin(nx) $$
which converges in distribution to

$$ 1+i\cot(x/2). $$

Comment: Can you elaborate " converges in distribution"?

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice simple solution. Regarding the "convergence in distribution", this comes from the fact that the function is not in $L_2$ or that we don't have pointwise convergence at $0$ (this is reflected by the $\cot$). At least, we have convergence in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{T})$ with no risk.